# Illegal State Exception Firebase Database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to use Firebase database but am facing an Illegal State Exception

> Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process com.example.
>   Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.

I created a Utility class that can be instantiated from anywhere. I have tried in both Application and Activity (onCreate) level and the result is the same.

```
public class FirebaseUtils {
    private static final String TAG = FirebaseUtils.class.getSimpleName();

    private static FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseDatabase;
    private static DatabaseReference mDbReference;

    // listeners
    private static OnFirebaseValueListener mFirebaseValueListener;

    /**
     * Method is used to set callback to listen to value changes in Firebase DB
     *
     * @param listener
     */
    public static void onFirebaseValueListener(OnFirebaseValueListener listener) {
        mFirebaseValueListener = listener;
    }

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public FirebaseUtils(Context context) {
        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(context);
        mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        mDbReference = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference();
    }

    /**
     * Method is used to add a list of values to Firebase DB
     *
     * @param alHistory
     */
    public static void addValues(List<?> alHistory) {
        if (!FrameworkUtils.checkIfNull(mDbReference)) {
            // set value
            mDbReference.setValue(alHistory);
            mDbReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "<onDataChange> successful!");
                    if (!FrameworkUtils.checkIfNull(mFirebaseValueListener)) {
                        mFirebaseValueListener.onDataChange(dataSnapshot);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    if (!FrameworkUtils.checkIfNull(databaseError) && !FrameworkUtils.isStringEmpty(databaseError.getMessage())) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "<onCancelled> error: " + databaseError.getMessage());
                        if (!FrameworkUtils.checkIfNull(mFirebaseValueListener)) {
                            mFirebaseValueListener.onCancelled(databaseError);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }

    /**
     * Method is used to retrieve a list of values from Firebase DB
     */
    public static void retrieveValues() {
        mDbReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                Log.i(TAG, "<onDataChange> successful!");
                if (!FrameworkUtils.checkIfNull(mFirebaseValueListener)) {
                    mFirebaseValueListener.onDataChange(dataSnapshot);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                if (!FrameworkUtils.checkIfNull(databaseError) && !FrameworkUtils.isStringEmpty(databaseError.getMessage())) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "<onCancelled> error: " + databaseError.getMessage());
                    if (!FrameworkUtils.checkIfNull(mFirebaseValueListener)) {
                        mFirebaseValueListener.onCancelled(databaseError);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I am instantiating like this

```
// instantiate FirebaseUtils
        new FirebaseUtils(this);
```

I have added all my dependencies in gradle

```
dependencies {       
     compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.2.1'
}
```

I have internet permission in Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Is there some sort of setup on Firebase that I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone who has attempted to give answers but these answers did not work. I figured it out. What I did was initialize FirebaseApp with options.

If anyone else has done all the steps for setting up Firebase database but is still receiving that illegal exception error, you may want to try to instantiate your FirebaseApp with options instead.

First create your options

```
FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
                .setApiKey("key")
                .setDatabaseUrl("url")
                .setApplicationId("ID")
                .build();
```

Now use that to instantiate FirebaseApp

```
FirebaseApp app = FirebaseApp.initializeApp(context, options);
```

Now that you have completed that step, instantiate your FirebaseDatabase

```
FirebaseDatabase firebaseDb = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(app);
```

You will be able to do the following

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = firebaseDb.getReference();
```